# MS Access user permissions using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is it possible to add permissions on multiple objects using SQL in Access like below?

```
GRANT SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE, DROP, SELECTSECURITY, UPDATESECURITY, UPDATEIDENTITY, CREATE
ON PERSON, INVOICE, CUSTOMER, EMPLOYEE
TO Developers
```

Answer (score 1):

The DDL GRANT and REVOKE statements seem to be available in specific versions of MS Access.

Access 2007, as documented here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177904(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177904%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Access 2013, as documented here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193820(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193820%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

The feature was not always there though. The MS-Jet 4.0 Engine (used by Access 2000) had them... but I can't find documentation on which version of Access/MS-Jet it first appeared in.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried to implement the code above after reading the documentation on those links but haven't had any success. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you open another question... stating exactly which version of Access you are using (things have changed a lot) and exactly what you have tried and what errors you are getting.