# Access SQL - ALTER COLUMN to AutoNumber?

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can you alter a table in MS Access using SQL to change a data type to AutoNumber?

I have tried to following with no success

```
ALTER TABLE PERSON ALTER COLUMN PERSON_ID Integer PRIMARY KEY counter
);
ALTER TABLE PERSON ALTER COLUMN PERSON_ID Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTONUMBER
);
ALTER TABLE PERSON ALTER COLUMN PERSON_ID Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
);
```

Each time I get the same issue "Syntax error" and it highlights the last word in the SQL.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For a Data Definition (DDL) query in Access you use `COUNTER` to define an AutoNumber field. You were trying to use both `Integer` and `counter` on the same field, and that won't work.

I just tried this and it worked for me in Access 2010:

```sql
ALTER TABLE PERSON ALTER COLUMN PERSON_ID COUNTER PRIMARY KEY
```

Note that in order for this statement to work

- the table must be empty, and
- the table must not already have a Primary Key, not even on the [PERSON_ID] field.

If the table already has rows in it then Access will not allow you to convert a `Numeric (Long Integer)` field to `AutoNumber`. In that case you need to create a new table with the AutoNumber Primary Key and then insert the rows from the old table into the new table.

For example, for an existing table named [PERSON] with columns

PERSON_ID INTEGER
PERSON_NAME TEXT(50)

you need to create a new table

```sql
CREATE TABLE PERSON_NEW (PERSON_ID COUNTER PRIMARY KEY, PERSON_NAME TEXT(50))
```

and then copy the records over

```sql
INSERT INTO PERSON_NEW
SELECT * FROM PERSON
```

Comment: unfortunately the table already has data in it. Is there any way that this will work if there is data? I am creating this table based on another table with the same name, fields, and all the data in the existing table(for a school project) Person_ID is also a FK in another table hence why I want to keep the data the same.

Comment: is there any chance I could get you to help with another question? I think it will be closed if I ask it in the main section

Comment: Do you know how in SQL I can allow a user to have read access to reports and data and the ability to create new reports? I have created a user group and user in SQL but don't know how to allow the user to create new reports

Comment: @WillNZ If you are referring to user-level security (ULS) in the Access database itself (as your other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24226606/2144390) seems to suggest) then I can't offer too much help with that, sorry. I never really used ULS and now that it has been deprecated (and removed from the .accdb file format) I just stick with my strategy of using file-level permissions to control read-only vs. read-write access on .accdb/.mdb files as a whole, and for anything more sophisticated I move the database back-end to SQL Server.

Comment: @Gord Thompson. +1 Brilliant solution. I learned something, that got me out of a pickle, thank you. I owe you a beer too.

Comment: @GordThompson..i am using ACCDB with SQL server linked tables. I have a table in SQL server which is numeric and is primary key, identity. when i link this table to MS Access , the data type is converted to numeric not Auto number ..so any insert is not working . can you pls help here ?

Comment: @GordThompson..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473113/sql-server-numeric-with-indentity-not-converting-to-auto-number-in-ms-access-usi . Here is the link for the question posted on SO..

Comment: Adding a new column won't do the job?