# SQL Server Numeric with Identity not converting to Auto Number in MS Access using linked tables

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, type-conversion, linked-tables

I am using ACCDB with SQL Server linked tables.

I have a table with a `Numeric` column, primary key and an identity column.

But when I link it to Access database, it is getting converted as `Number` and not `Auto Number`.

Any thoughts how to correct this?

Comment: If you insert a row into the linked table does the identity column get an automatically-generated value?

Comment: If the table is linked Access has nothing to do with auto-incrementing that number anyway. You write in your data in all the other columns and Sql Server takes care of the incrementing.

Comment: No..the insert is not working..i guess it is not auto incrementing

Comment: @Brad..Just an Update .you are correct ..SQL Server does the increment..so no issues even if Access does not show it as Auto Number..Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @GordThompson ..It is giving the auto generated value..so no issues..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An autonumber in Access is actually a long integer (int in SQL Server), with an additional property creating an autonumber. If your SQL Server data type is actually numeric, I don't see how Access can recognize it as an autonumber. When using Access as a front end to SQL Server, it is best to use data types that Access easily recognizes.