# How to change PK from access table?

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an Access database.

There is a way to set a PK Filed from my table as Automatic Number?

Now I have a table with the field ID as PK Number (and in this tablet there are some data), now I want to set automatic number as PK.

There is a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access SQL - ALTER COLUMN to AutoNumber?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24238068/access-sql-alter-column-to-autonumber)

Comment: If the table already has data, you cannot change a Number PK to Autonumber. See answer on linked question.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the Table in question and go to the Design View. From there find the field you want to change to AutoNumber. Keep in mind that only one field can be set to Autonumber (there are work arounds to this limitation) and that I'm pretty sure you cannot have any data in the table or any relationship links connected to the table.

Just as a side note tip, unless the ID of the rows do not necessarily matter, Making the ID of the rows Autonumber inst always the best practice. Certain cases where you need IDs to be sequential(Not skipping over IDs) is a good example of where an Autonumber PK is not a good idea.

Comment: Instead of simply down voting my answer. How about providing some constructive criticism on how this is not a good answer.